# Finding the rate of change of an algebra equation

Tags: slope

I'm trying to help my daughter with her math homework and after scouring google and websites I find I truly do not understand how to complete this even after going several different websites.

The problem is 2y - 12x = 36

I need to understand how to complete this problem so I can then explain it to her.

I've tried using sites like tiger-algebra and I realize it's just above my head...

Please assist a desperate father.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by rearranging so that you've got a "y" on its own: the first problem that we notice is that "2" stuck to the front, so we'll divide both sides by 2 to get rid of it, obtaining $$y - 6x = 18.$$
Now, that "$-6x$" is in the way, so we'll add $6x$ to both sides to get rid of it, obtaining $$y = 6x + 18.$$

That should get it into the standard form that you're expecting for "rate of change" questions, and it's clear that the rate of change is $6$.

Comment: Ok, that helped simplify it for me, I was having trouble with all the extra info the website was providing.  thank you!